# Preserve comments in Vite

Tags: javascript, typescript, comments, vite

When I run Vite in dev or build mode, it automatically removes any comments in JavaScript/TypeScript files. Is there a way to get Vite to keep the comments?

EDIT: I've tried adding `"removeComments": false,` to `tsconfig.json` but that didn't work.

Comment: vite uses rollup to build, maybe check the options for rollup?

Comment: I've tried to look and didn't find. But I think Vite uses Rollup only for build. For dev it uses esbuild.

Comment: i'm curious, why do you need comments?

Comment: The built version will get reviewed and it's easier to understand with comments.

Comment: have you looked at sourcemaps?

Comment: @siria - Interesting, you mean by something like an app store review process?

Comment: Yes. With sourcemap enabed the comments still do not appear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, something like that. Also would like the final code to be readable regardless.

Comment: Related https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4850#issuecomment-1429657718